# atom.io snippets not working

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I wrote a simple Atom.io snippet for ReactJS:

```
'.text.js':
'React Component':
'prefix': 'rrc'
'body': 'var Component = React.createClass({ 
                render: function(){
                    return { 
                        ; 
                    }  
                } 
            })'
```

I saved this to

> atom/resources/app/dot-atom/snippets.cson

file where snippets live, and after trying it by typing `'rrc'` and hitting tab key, I got only a *blank space*.

I googled around and other people were having similar problem, but I found no solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to Atom's [snippet documentation](https://github.com/atom/snippets) it appears that the source selector should be '.source.js' rather than '.text.js'

Also, you'll need to make it a multiline snippet as well:

```
'.source.js':
  'React Component':
  'prefix': 'rrc'
  'body': """
     var Component = React.createClass({ 
        render: function(){
          return { 
              ; 
          }  
        } 
      })
   """
```

Comment: You are right, but still no luck - when I type rrc and hit tab nothing happens. :(

Comment: I was able to get this to work by retyping it into my snippets.cson.  Unfortunately, there seems to be an issue with snippets not triggering properly because I have new snippets in my file that do not trigger when multiple source classes are used in the snippets file.  Here's the bug: [link](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues/80)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, content is exactly as provided by josh, but try to keep the exact spacing. I just tried it on 1.12.3 and no issues.

```
'.source.js':
  'React Component':
    'prefix': 'rrc'
    'body': """
    var Component = React.createClass({ 
        render: function(){
            return {
                ;
            }
        }
    })"""
```

[image: snippet]

Open new tab, give the proper syntax.

[image: set proper syntax]

Type rrc then tab, or enter if you select from the autocomplete.

[image: autocomplete should suggest snippet]

[image: snippet is expanded]

Comment: Please put the code directly into the post and not in an image.